# AngularJS directive communication and page template - inner directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have some trouble with directive communication and in particular with inner and outer custom tags.

So, I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<title>Directives</title>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <outer>
        <inner></inner>
    </outer>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have the following JavaScript code for my AngularJS directives:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("outer", function() {
    return {
        template: "<div>This is outer message</div>",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        controller: function() {
            this.say = function(message) {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive("inner", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "^outer",
        replace: false,
        controller: function($scope) {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, outerCtrl) {
            outerCtrl.say("This is inner message");
        }
    }
});
```

It looks very simple. I want to display one message to the screen and another one to console logger. But the second one doesn't appear until I comment `template: "<div>This is outer message</div>"` line! I suppose that the problem is connected with page rendering (link and compile functions). Actually I've got confused with it and I can't fix this bug.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide a template, it will replace the content of `<outer>` (the `replace` option only controls whether the `<outer>` tag is replaced as well).

Because of that, the `<inner>` directive is no longer linked. If you want to provide a template while still linking the inner tag. You need to use a transclusion:

```
app.directive("outer", function() {
    return {
        template: "<div>This is outer message <div ng-transclude></div></div>",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        controller: function() {
            this.say = function(message) {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This will insert inner inside the div with `ng-transclude`.

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled upon the answer to your own question.  The `template` option of the `outer` directive will replace the elements

```
<outer>
  <inner></inner>
<outer>
```

with your template to just be

```
<div>This is outer message</div>
```

thus removing the inner directive from being instantiated.  Take a look at the difference of the DOM using your dev tools to see how it's different using the template and not using it